# Cucumber-JVM with Gradle, how to run tests automatically

Tags: gradle, cucumber-jvm

I'm working on a Java project that uses Gradle as its build system.

I want to add some bdd tests using Cucumber-JVM. Following [this example](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/examples/java-gradle) I was able to configure Gradle's build.gradle to have a task called cucumber, and I was able to execute that task using "gradle cucumber".

But what I am looking for is a way to have Gradle run that task automatically during its test phase (where it runs all the other regular unit tests). I also want the build to be flagged as failed if any of the cucumber tests fail (strict=true).

Is this possible? I don't know a lot about Gradle and Google so  far has produced nothing really useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I figured out how to achieve this. Simply add this to build.gradle:

```
test << {
        javaexec {
            main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['--strict', '--monochrome', '--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'com.mypackage', 'src/test/resources']
        }
}
```

All you really need are the feature file and the steps java files that implement the glue code. You do not need the xxxCukesTest.java file with a @RunWith annotation since Gradle ignores it. You may want to keep it anyway because it enables you to run tests from your IDE.

Works really neat!

Comment: In case someone needs to achieve this in an Android project this might come in handy: The above method did not work for me because it's based on the Java plugin for Gradle which is incompatible with the Android plugin. The solution for I've found  is based on the `unitTests.all` hook that Android provides. Details can be found in my SO question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52348197/how-to-make-cucumber-features-run-in-an-android-project-as-local-unit-tests/52523306#52523306 & in this blog post here:https://www.urig.io/blog/android-run-cucumber-tests-without-a-device-or-an-emulator