# How to make Cucumber features run in an Android project as local unit tests?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have an Android project written in Java that I'm working on in Android Studio.

I'd like to use Cucumber for integration testing of some internal components (note: I know this is not the BDD way, nonetheless useful to me). I want the tests to run as [local unit tests](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line) (without Instrumentation) using `gradlew test` because the components under test do not interact with the Android SDK.

**My problem is that the Cucumber features are not recognized by Gradle and do not run when I run `gradlew test`.**

Here's how I set it up so far:

1. Added these dependencies to my app's build.gradle:

   ```
   testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:3.0.2'
   testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:3.0.2'
   testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-jvm:3.0.2'
   ```
2. Also there, I added the path to where I've put my Feature file:

   ```
   android {
       ...
       sourceSets {
           test {
               assets.srcDirs = ['src/test/java/integrationTest/assets']
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   This is based on this folder structure:

   [image]
3. Added a class for the steps (`Steps1.java`) as can be seen above.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Just checking-  you know junit is built in and does non-instrumented unit tests, right?  I doubt you'll find too many people who use cucumber given the ease of using junit.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks.  I'm aware of that. Perhaps the baked in JUnit test runner is responsible for my features being ignored?

Comment: Possibly. Also I see cucumber-jvm there. Android doesn't ruin the jvm it runs art. There could be issues there.

Comment: @GabeSechan what is "art"? Can I perhaps configure it to also run my Cucumber JUnit tests on top of the regular Android unit tests?

Comment: art is an alternative virtual machine.  JVM is Oracle's (formerly Sun's).  There are differences in the bytecode and other things, if something assumes jvm it may not run on art.  But if you can get the test to run from Android Studio then that's not likely a problem

Comment: Thanks.  I now think the default test runner for Android local unit tests is responsible for my features being ignored.  Likely I need to customize my gradle.build file to also run the Cucumber test runner in the 'test' task.  Trying to learn how to do that now.  Would love to get help with that if anyone knows how to get it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out how to configure my Android app to run my Cucumber tests as "local unit tests" when I run `gradlew test` from the command line. This is based on my [SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52474366/gradle-for-android-why-doesnt-javaexec-pick-up-my-classpath) and I've written a "HOWTO" blog post about it here: [Android: Run Cucumber tests without a device or an emulator](https://www.urig.io/blog/android-run-cucumber-tests-without-a-device-or-an-emulator).

The key to getting it done is in the app's `build.gradle` file. By latching on to the `unitTests.all` hook in the `testOptions` section I am able to run Cucumber using `javaexec` like so:

```
android {
    ...
    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            def classpath2 = getClasspath()
            javaexec {
                main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
                classpath = classpath2
                args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'gradle.cucumber', 'src/test/java/cucumber/assets']
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I provided another way to directly run unit tests using the Cucumber Custom Runner class. Refer to my answer below. This also applies for kotlin project.

Answer (score 1):

Your feature files are probably not getting picked up because you did not include a runner. You can either create a [JUnit Runner](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/v3.0.2/junit) or use the [Gradle cucumber plugin](https://github.com/samueltbrown/gradle-cucumber-plugin). I am not sure if either would work in Android though.

Also you don't need `io.cucumber:cucumber-jvm:3.0.2` as a dependency. It is only a pom.

Comment: Thanks. If I roll my own JUnit runner for the Cucumber tests how do I ensure other regular unit tests will also run?

Comment: I've tried embedding the Gradle Cucumber plugin in my `build.gradle` but if fails with *"The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins."*. So I guess it's just not going to work the Android?

Comment: I've also tried the other approach by adding a JUnit Runner class to my app. I can run it from Android Studio but `gradlew test` still ignores it.

Comment: Did you add `testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'`?

Answer (score 0):

Or there is another way to directly run android unit tests from a custom runner. This is easiest approach for kotlin Android project.

In my app-level build.gradle,

```
dependencies {
   //Cucumber
   testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-java:7.13.0")
   testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:7.13.0")
   testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-jvm:7.13.0")
}
```

Then as shown in picture below, I managed to run a cucumber scenario through the CucumberTestRunner green run arrow.

[image]

**Sample Source Code**

For any entity data class **UserEntity.kt**,

```
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "users")
data class UserEntity(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
    val name: String
)
```

I first, created a feature file named **UserEntityBdd.feature** as,

```
Feature: UserEntity class behavior

  Scenario: Create a new UserEntity
    Given a user ID
    And a user name
    When a UserEntity is created
    Then the UserEntity should have the given ID and name
```

Then, corresponding steps definitions file named **UserEntityStepDefinitions.kt** as,

```
import com.example.mvvm.datalayer.model.UserEntity
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then
import io.cucumber.java.en.When
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
import kotlin.properties.Delegates

class UserEntityStepDefinitions {
    private var userId by Delegates.notNull<Int>()
    private lateinit var userName: String
    private lateinit var userEntity: UserEntity

    @Given("a user ID")
    fun givenUserId() {
        userId = 123
    }

    @Given("a user name")
    fun givenUserName() {
        userName = "John Doe"
    }

    @When("a UserEntity is created")
    fun createUserEntity() {
        userEntity = UserEntity(userId, userName)
    }

    @Then("the UserEntity should have the given ID and name")
    fun checkUserEntity() {
        assertEquals(userId, userEntity.id)
        assertEquals(userName, userEntity.name)
    }
}
```

and finally the Cuccumber Custom Runner, named **CucumberTestRunner.kt**, as

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(Cucumber::class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = ["."], // The package where your feature files are located
    glue = ["."], // The package where your step definitions are located
    plugin = ["pretty", "html:reports/test-report"] // Report plugins
)
class CucumberTestRunner
```

And doing this approach made me I don't need to convert/port below groovy snippet to kts

```
testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            def classpath2 = getClasspath()
            javaexec {
                main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
                classpath = classpath2
                args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'gradle.cucumber', 'src/test/java/cucumber/assets']
            }
        }
    }
```